# Convert array to comma-delimited string without trailing comma

Tags: php, foreach, delimited

Quick PHP problem here :

When doing a for each statement I have to echo it in a perticular syntax I.E

```
|First_Name:bob,jim,alex,gary|Last_Name:Smith,Doe,foo|Age:11,12,13
```

I have so far manage to achieve this syntax except for the last value of each of the for loop as I get this result

```
|First_Name:bob,jim,alex,gary,|Last_Name:Smith,Doe,foo,|Age:11,12,13,
```

so the is an extra comma in every itteration of the second loop.

Is there a way to get rid of the comma for the last value only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in function for joining array elements, called [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), which I suggest you should use:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
$s = implode(",", $a);

// result: "1,2,3"
```

NB: The short array notation was introduced in PHP 5.4. For older versions, use this line instead to initialize an array:

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer that actually looked at the question and realised i was in a loop haha. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$abc = "First_Name:bob,jim,alex,gary,";
$rest = substr($abc, -1);
```